# Validation array (unique link) in update function

Tags: php, laravel

how to pass id with link, because id link is unique.

```
    This code update socials and send data by array, how to send id to link every every-time

    $ids = $request->get('id');
    $link = $request->get('link');
    $icon = $request->get('icon');
    $status = $request->get('status');
    //////////////////////////
    $validator = Validator::make([
        'link' => $link,
        'icon' => $icon,
    ], [
        'link.*' => 'required|unique:socials,link,' . $ids,
        'icon.*' => 'required',
    ]);
    //////////////////////////
    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        $request->session()->flash('danger', $validator->messages());
        return redirect(route('socials.view'))->withInput();
    }
    else
    {
        foreach ($ids as $id)
        {
            $social = new Social();
            $info = $social->getSocial($id);
            if($info)
            {
                $social->updateSocial($info,$link[$id],$icon[$id],$status[$id]);
            }
        }
        $request->session()->flash('success', parent::UPDATE_SUCCESS_MESSAGE);
        return redirect(route('socials.view'));
    }
```

This code update socials and send data by array, how to send id to link every every-time.

when execute this code , the result ( Array to string conversion )

Comment: what is the output of ids? please `var_dump`

Comment: @JeesKDenny This is result
array:3 [▼
  0 => "1"
  1 => "2"
  2 => "3"
]